# Prove that an ideal is a radical ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, ideals

I'm working on a problem, where I don't know how to "get my hands on".

I want to show that the ideal $J$ of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, which is generated by the $2 \times 2$-minors of the matrix $$M= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_{n-1} \\
x_1 &x_2&x_3&\dots&x_n
\end{pmatrix}$$ is a radical ideal.

You could also write $J=(x_2-x_1^2,x_1x_3-x_2^2,x_2x_4-x_3^2,\dots,x_{n-2}x_n-x_{n-1}^2)$

I know that a prime ideal is a radical ideal, so I try to show that $J$ is prime by showing that the corresponding variety $V(J)$ is irreducible. Now I have problems to find a starting point, so if anyone could give ma a hint or a "path" to prove the problem I'd be very thankful.
If I'm on the wrong way please tell me.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$J=(x_2-x_1^2, \dots, x_n-x_1x_{n-1},x_1x_n-x_2x_{n-1},\dots, x_{n-2}x_n-x_{n-1}^2).$$

Moreover, $\Bbb C[x_1,\ldots, x_n]/J\simeq\mathbb C[x_1]$, so $J$ is a prime ideal. (Notice that $x_2$ is replaced by $x_1^2$, $x_3$ by $x_1^3$, and so on. Thus all the $2\times 2$ minors of the matrix $M$ with the first column removed become zero.)

Answer (score 2):

A hint is to use the fact that $J$ is irreducible iff its vanishing set $V(J)$ is irreducible (as a topological space with the Zariski topology). Using this, the solution goes as follows:

> $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in V(J)$ iff$$(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=\lambda(1,a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})$$for some $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, i.e, $a_i=\lambda^i$ for each $i$. Hence, we have a surjective map\begin{align*}\mathbb{C}&\longrightarrow V(J)\\\lambda&\longmapsto (\lambda,\dots,\lambda^n),\end{align*}and as $\mathbb{C}$ is irreducible and the map is continuos, $V(J)$ is also irreducible. This implies that $J$ is irreducible as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it true, that a variety, which ist parametrizable via rational functions is irreduzible? How can I prove that, without using the concept of continuos maps?