# Equality of ideals in $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

I want to show that two ideals $I,J \subset \mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ are equal.

Let $I=(X_iX_{k+1}-X_{i+1}X_k)$ for $0\leq i \leq n-2$ and $1 \leq k \leq n-1$, with $X_0=1$ and $i < k$.

Let $J = (X_j-X_1^j)$ with $2\leq j \leq n$.

I want to show $I=J$, but I'm unable to start. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4283999 where the (same) OP denoted by $J$ the first ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $i=0$, we get $X_{k+1}-X_1X_k\in I$ for $k\ge 1$, i.e. $X_1X_{j-1}\equiv X_j$ for $j\ge 2$. Then by induction, $$X_1^j = X_1X_1^{j-1} \equiv X_1X_{j-1} \equiv X_j \text{ mod } I$$

This shows that $J\subset I$.

For the other direction, $$X_iX_{k+1}-X_{i+1}X_k\equiv X_1^i X_1^{k+1} - X_1^{i+1}X_1^k=0\text{ mod } J$$

So $I\subset J$ as well.

Comment: Thank you! In the first equation $X_1X_1^{j-1} \equiv X_1 X_{j-1}$ holds because by our induction hypothesis $X_{j-1}-X_1^{j-1} \equiv 0 \mod I$, right?

Comment: Right (and base case is trivial)